# Cant show heighmap on graph

Tags: python, geocoding, geopandas, shapefile

It is not possible to display the graph of the height map. I cant found any problem in code, but graph is empty. Someone can maybe explain how to create shp files for projects like that one. I dont understand:
I need to add some fields in shp?
Some problem with code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
from shapely.geometry import Point
from os.path import join as pth_join
import json
import time

#Configure API request link
request_str = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7177537,-105.1961914&key=(API here)"

#Define data inputs and outputs
data_root = r"C:\Users\K11El\Desktop\gg"
input_file = "loca.shp"
output_file = input_file[:-4]+"_elev.shp"
#Read input file into a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.read_file(pth_join(data_root,input_file))
gdf_wgs = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
#Extract x,y from geometry and convert to strings
build_str = gdf_wgs['geometry'].apply(lambda v: ("%s,%s|" % (str(v.y), str(v.x))))
#Limit each request to 512
geom = []
iterations = int(len(build_str)/512) + 1
for x in range(iterations):
    iter_str = build_str[x*512:(x+1)*512]
    #Build concatenated string for API request
    locs = "".join([x for x in iter_str]).rstrip('|')

    #Make request, parse results
    r = requests.get(request_str)
    parsed = json.loads(r.text)

    #Extract elevations from result
    geom = geom + [Point(i['location']['lng'],i['location']
                         ['lat'],i['elevation']) for i in parsed['results']]

    #Slow down API requests so we aren't blocked
    time.sleep(1)
# Save to new file with x,y,z and reproject to CRS of input file
gdf_elev = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geom}, crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf_elev.to_crs(gdf.crs).to_file(pth_join(data_root, output_file))
#Check results with a simple plot
gdf_elev['elevation'] = gdf_elev['geometry'].apply(lambda v: (v.z))
gdf_elev.plot("elevation",legend=True,legend_kwds={'label': "Elevation (Meters)"})
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you making 3000 subplots?

Comment: Oh, its my fail... but that dont solve my problem

Comment: what are you really trying to achieve, color points on a plot where color is elevation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using **osmnx** it's straight forward to use it's implementation of getting elevation from **google**

```
# add x & y columns for osmnx
cities = cities.join(
    cities["geometry"].apply(lambda p: {"x": p.x, "y": p.y}).apply(pd.Series)
)

# create graph
G = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(cities, gpd.GeoDataFrame(), graph_attrs=None)
# add elevations using google
G = ox.add_node_elevations_google(G, key)

# now have elevation for all points
gdf = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=False).set_crs(cities.crs)
```

- sample data including elevation

| osmid | name_left | iso_a3 | x | y | elevation | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vatican City | ITA | 12.4534 | 41.9033 | 24.887 | POINT (12.453386544971766 41.903282179960115) |
| 1 | San Marino | ITA | 12.4418 | 43.9361 | 377.216 | POINT (12.441770157800141 43.936095834768004) |
| 2 | Rome | ITA | 12.4813 | 41.8979 | 18.527 | POINT (12.481312562873995 41.89790148509894) |
| 3 | Vaduz | AUT | 9.51667 | 47.1337 | 513.964 | POINT (9.516669472907267 47.13372377429357) |
| 4 | Vienna | AUT | 16.3647 | 48.202 | 185.284 | POINT (16.364693096743736 48.20196113681686) |
| 5 | Luxembourg | LUX | 6.13 | 49.6117 | 303.25 | POINT (6.130002806227083 49.611660379121076) |
| 6 | Monaco | -99 | 7.40691 | 43.7396 | 293.219 | POINT (7.406913173465057 43.73964568785249) |
| 7 | Andorra | -99 | 1.51649 | 42.5 | 1378.3 | POINT (1.5164859605055199 42.5000014435459) |
| 8 | Paris | -99 | 2.33139 | 48.8686 | 35.89 | POINT (2.33138946713035 48.86863878981461) |
| 9 | Ljubljana | SVN | 14.515 | 46.0553 | 290.773 | POINT (14.51496903347413 46.0552883087945) |

#### full code

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import contextily as ctx

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities")).sjoin(
    world.loc[world["continent"].eq("Europe")]
)

cities = cities.loc[:, ["name_left", "iso_a3", "geometry"]].reset_index(drop=True)
# add x & y columns for osmnx
cities = cities.join(
    cities["geometry"].apply(lambda p: {"x": p.x, "y": p.y}).apply(pd.Series)
)

# create graph
G = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(cities, gpd.GeoDataFrame(), graph_attrs=None)
# add elevations using google
G = ox.add_node_elevations_google(G, key)

# now have elevation for all points
gdf = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=False).set_crs(cities.crs)


ax = gdf.plot(
    column="elevation",
    figsize=[12, 4],
    markersize=100,
    vmax=gdf["elevation"].quantile(0.9),
    legend=True,
)
gdf.apply(
    lambda x: ax.annotate(
        text=x["name_left"],
        xy=x.geometry.coords[0],
        ha="center",
        xytext=(0, 10),
        textcoords="offset points",
    ),
    axis=1,
)

ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=gdf.crs, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.Terrain)
```

#### output

[image]